# parallel include function in PHP?

Tags: php, cron

So basically I've got a **cron.php** file which I use as a bootstrap file instead of setting a ton of different **Cron Jobs**, I want to be able to do an include on all my separate Cron files at the same time instead of waiting for the 1st to finish, then the second etc...

Here's my current **cron.php** file:

```
/*
* run this file every minute to execute all crons
*/

$included_cron = true;

ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
require "files/core.php";

/*===== 1st Cron! =====*/

    include ROOT.'/files/crons/file1.php';

/*===== 2nd Cron! =====*/

    include ROOT.'/files/crons/file2.php';

/*===== 3rd Cron! =====*/

    include ROOT.'/files/crons/file3.php';
```

How can I do it so I can have `file3.php` included at the same time as `file1.php`, is that possible in PHP?

Comment: Multithreading is most likely out of scope for PHP by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question is:

```
<?php
class CronJob extends Threaded {

    public function __construct($file) {
        $this->file = $file;
    }

    public function run() {
        require_once("files/cron/{$this->file}");
    }

    protected $file;
}

$workers = 4;

$pool = new Pool($workers);

foreach (["file1.php", "file2.php", "file3.php"] as $file) {
    $pool->submit(
        new CronJob($file));
}

$pool->shutdown();
?>
```

This does feel quite horrible though, it's likely going to be better to just write each cron job as a threaded object, where ::run contains business logic for each of your cron tasks.

```
<?php

class FirstJob extends Threaded {
    public function __construct(Threaded $config) {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    public function run() {
        /* do stuff for this cron job */
    }

    protected $config;
}

class SecondJob extends Threaded {
    public function __construct(Threaded $config) {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    public function run() {
        /* do stuff for this cron job */
    }

    protected $config;
}

class ThirdJob extends Threaded {
    public function __construct(Threaded $config) {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    public function run() {
        /* do stuff for this cron job */
    }

    protected $config;
}

$workers = 4;

$config = new Threaded();
$config["database"] = [
    "username" => "mine",
    "password" => "secret",
    "hostname" => "localhost",
    "database" => "data"    
];


$pool = new Pool($workers);
/* probably come up with something better, get classes from a database or configuration source or whatever */
$pool->submit(new FirstJob($config));
$pool->submit(new SecondJob($config));
$pool->submit(new ThirdJob($config));
$pool->shutdown();
?>
```

Something like that ...

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called multithreading. It's not defaultly(without extensions) supported by php. What you can do instead, is to create http request to your other scripts.

cron.php

```
 function http_head($url){
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
 curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 }
 http_head("file1_url");
 http_head("file2_url");
```

If your cron does something sensitive (you don't want google crawler, or random user to trigger your cron) you should implement some kind of check, whether it's called by your cron (for example by IP address).

In file*.php you should tell php not to abort after caller closes connection.
    ignore_user_abort(true);

Comment: You say that PHP does not support multi-threading out of the box but then suggest parallel calls to `file_get_contents()`. I suspect you've forgotten to explain some detail, such as making the different scripts intermediately close the connection and work on background :-?

Comment: Thank you, it should make sense now

Answer (score 0):

If you need a single entry point for all your tasks but you want multi-tasking you'll have to use a language that supports it. PHP doesn't.

The most obvious choice is bash:

```
#!/bin/sh
php /path/to/cron.php file1 &
php /path/to/cron.php file2 &
php /path/to/cron.php file3 &
php /path/to/cron.php file4 &
```

And now you only need to tweak `cron.php` to accept a command line argument:

```
if (isset($argv[1]) ) {
    $task = $argv[1];
}else{
    echo "Must specify task\n";
    exit(1);
}
switch($task){
    case 'file1':
    case 'file2':
    case 'file3':
    case 'file4':
        break;
    default:
        echo "Invalid task: $task\n";
        exit(2);
}

include ROOT . "/files/crons/$task.php";
```

Comment: A very interesting choice, I'll look into this a little further, thanks!